# How to use a object literal to translate single words to another language in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I made a simple program that you should type the color it appears on a random word.
It works fine in English, but when I tried to "translate" it to my native language I couldn't.

```
let transl = {
vermelho : "red",
azul:"blue",
amarelo : "yellow",
verde : "green",
branco : "white",
}
```

I collect his input in my native language  `var namePT = document.getElementById(...).value;`
But how can I use this variable? Since it's a string I can't simply use `transl.namePT;`
So how do i convert this string variable to a variable that can be used in the object literal.
I hope I didn't make this too confusing or something.

Btw, I'm still new to javascript so give me a break for any stupid mistakes :)

Comment: does does `transl[namePT]` work for you?

Comment: you could use `transl[namePT]`